# SQL insertion error

Tags: oracle

I am doing a Dimensional modeling exercise in college and I have two tables labelled tournament 1 and tournament 2. In the tables there is a column called total_price. When loading the data from both of these tables into my Dim_table known as Dim_tournament I need to change the value of the total_price to euros. I have been trying to use the command that is given below but it does not work.

```
insert into Dim_tournament (Tournament_SK, total_price, Tournament_DESC)
Select seq_Tournament.nextVal, total_price, t_descriprion  From (
select t_id, to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00'), t_descriprion from Tournament1
union all
select t_id, to_char(total_price, 'C9,999,999.00'), t_descriprion from Tournament2
order by total_price);
```

I keep getting this error every time I try to run it.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TOTAL_PRICE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out there myself. I changed the total_price variable in the Dim_tournament table to char and then used to_char(total_price, 'C9999,999.00') as total_price alias and it worked. The problem was the data type. lovely.

Comment: You shouldn't store numbers in `varchar` columns. That's a really bad decision.